# Angular 5 Asp.net Core CloudFlare SSL - Browser Back button glitch

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0, cloudflare, server-side-rendering

Bit of a weird issue! I have an app that uses Angular 5.0.0 with Asp.net Core 2.0 for an Api and server side rendering.  I recently created a subdomain, and added that to my free cloudflare so that I can use ssl to test a service worker.

I found that if I used the browser back button, rather than change the page, it just added to it e.g. If I go to Page A, B, Then C using nav links, then click back to return to A, I get a page that has all of them!?

Looking in the console, the only error I find is:

> [Show/hide message details.] Error: Permission denied to access property "apply"[Learn More] main-client.js:489:800
>   nn
>   https://coblandhorses.digital-jeeves.co.uk/dist/main-client.js:489:800
>   s
>   https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/4f936b58/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js:1:8500

My concern is that when I want to put this site permanently live, it will have the same issue.

I removed the service worker, so I know it's not that.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the problem was the broken script in the error (duh!) I disabled rocket loader in my cloudflare dashboard, and now everything works... Now I feel a little stupid given the time I spent on this... Anyway, should you have issues like this, check for broken scripts...